# Regex that will find the description in a transaction

Tags: python, regex

Compiling Lines of text in the format,

```
26 Jan The Gym Debit Card Transaction £656.40
```

I'm able to compile the date, Value of transaction and what type of transcation but unsure how to compile the description (The Gym), as it varies in length and spaces depending on each line of code.

```py
company_re = re.compile(r'[^\d+ \w{3}+\(Debit Card Transaction Mobile|Online Transacti…|Direct Debit|Standing Order|Automated Credit|)\£\d+.\d\d]')
```

This was my last attempt, my idea was to reject everything that was in a fixed pattern but it doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DD35yp/1)):

Note: I've used verbose flag [`(?x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.X) to make the pattern more readable

```py
import re

pattern = r'''(?x)
(\d+\s\w{3})\s                              # match the date
(.*?)                                       # match the name
(                                           # match the transaction type
    Debit\ Card\ Transaction |
    Debit\ Card\ Transaction\ Mobile |
    Standing\ Order |
    Debit\ Card\ Transaction
)\s
(\£\d+\.?\d*)                               # match the amount
'''

text = '''\
26 Jan The Gym Debit Card Transaction £656.40
16 Dec Other stuff Standing Order £56.40
1 Feb Some Other stuff Debit Card Transaction Mobile £6'''

for date, name, type_, amount in re.findall(pattern, text):
    print(date, name, type_, amount, sep='\n')
    print('-'*80)
```

Prints:

```
26 Jan
The Gym 
Debit Card Transaction
£656.40
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
16 Dec
Other stuff 
Standing Order
£56.40
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 Feb
Some Other stuff 
Debit Card Transaction Mobile
£6
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This helps, thanks alot. I also wanted to further ask. Some transactions don't include dates e.g 
09 Jun Shop Debit Card Transaction £2.60
           Shop Debit Card Transaction £1.60
How can I indicate that both Transaction occurred on the same day using regex. Thanks again.

Comment: @Puj You can try to make the first group optional https://regex101.com/r/b9zGvP/1

Answer (score 0):

Issues with your current approach:

- You're putting everything in a single negated character set: `[^...]`. This completely breaks the RegEx and makes no sense.
- You can't possibly exhaustively enumerate all possible descriptions. This is also very-error prone. You should instead identify the "middle part" (the description) by what it is not: It is not the date or the value.
- You forgot to escape the decimal dot `.` in your RegEx; your RegEx would've matched any character between the digits of the value

So here's the RegEx I propose: [`(\d+\s+\w{3}+)\s+(.+?)\s+(£\d+\.\d\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/qFrCMs/1)

- `(\d+\s+\w{3}+)`: Match and capture the date, same as in your RegEx
- `\s+(.+?)\s+`: Match and capture a space-delimited "middle part" (description), make it as short as possible (we don't want spaces to go into the description)
- `(£\d+\.\d\d)`: Match and capture a trailing value of transaction in pounds

Make sure to use [`re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) for each line or to use the `^` and `$` anchors.